# Is there a way to call a method when a CAKeyframeAnimation finishes animating?

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I'm using Swift and I need to do some things once a `CAKeyframeAnimation` finishes.

If this were a `UIView` I would normally just use a `UIView.animateWithDuration` and would just implement this stuff in the `completionHandler` like so:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: [],
        animations: { },
        completion: {
            (animationFinished: Bool) in

            if animationFinished {
            // DO SOME STUFF IN HERE ONCE THE ANIMATION FINISHES
            }
    })
```

What is the equivalent way of doing this using `CAKeyframeAnimation`?

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured out how to do this.

Here's some example code you can paste into a playground in Xcode:

```
import XCPlayground

class BallAnimation: NSObject { // <- STEP 1 - INHERIT FROM NSOBJECT
  func doMyAnimation() {
    // Make a test background.
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = backgroundView

    // Create the object that will be animated and add it to the background.
    let ballImage = UIImage(named: "ball")
    let ballView = UIImageView(image: ballImage)
    backgroundView.addSubview(ballView)

    // Create the path the object will follow.
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 200, y:100))

    // Create the animation that will use the path we just created.
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.path = path.CGPath
    animation.duration = 2.0
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.delegate = self // <- STEP 2 - SET THE DELEGATE

    // This should start the animation
    ballView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animate ball")
  }

  // STEP 3 - OVERRIDE THIS METHOD
  override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    // When the animation stops it should call this method (make sure the delegate was set above).
    print("Animation did stop.")
  }
}

// Create an instance of the class and call the method that starts the animation.
let ballAnimation = BallAnimation()
ballAnimation.doMyAnimation()
```

**EXPLANATION**

The `CAAnimation` class adds the following method to `NSObject`:

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool)
```

So if a class inherits from `NSObject` it can be set as a `CAKeyframeAnimation` delegate and can override `animationDidStop` to perform other tasks when the animation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in XCode 12:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CAAnimationDelegate {

func creatAnimation() {
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
// some code configuring animation
animation.delegate = self
}

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        print("done")
        
 }
}
```